# Bitwise operations in Apache Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I'm looking at the [reference manual](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Arithmetic+Operators+and+More) and can't find any documentation of bitwise operations/functions.

Is there any way to use, for example, a bitwise AND operation (equivalent to "A & B" in Hive) in a Pig script?

Comment: If there is no direct support, you can use DEFINE to call outer scripts in perl, bash, etc. Create a simple scripts like bitwise_or, bitwise_and, and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can provide custom UDF for this. eg. see https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/udf.html

In pig script you would do

```
REGISTER myudfs.jar;
```

And example for BinaryAND UDF:

```
package myudfs;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.impl.util.WrappedIOException;

public class BitwiseAND extends EvalFunc (Integer)
{
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        // check input tuple:
        if (input == null || input.size() < 2)
            return null;
        try{
            return (Integer)input.get(0) & (Integer)input.get(1);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw WrappedIOException.wrap("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: This is not tested, it's just copied from the pig udf page.